# Why doesn't np.random.seed(0) make array creation determinstic?

Tags: python, numpy

In order to have deterministic result, I tried using `np.random.seed(0)` but I noticed, it does not work as I have assumed. A simple snippet to demonstrate this is as follows :

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)
error = np.random.rand(2,5)
print('error: \n' ,error)
```

The snippet above, creates the following output:

```
error: 
 [[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338  0.54488318  0.4236548 ]
 [ 0.64589411  0.43758721  0.891773    0.96366276  0.38344152]]
```

I can run the code as many times as I like and the output is deterministic as assumed. but when I try to create a second array this is not the case any more!

The snippet below, shows this :

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)
error = np.random.rand(2,5)
error2 = np.random.rand(2,5)
print('error: \n' ,error)
print('error2: \n' ,error2)
```

Outputs :

```
error: 
 [[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338  0.54488318  0.4236548 ]
 [ 0.64589411  0.43758721  0.891773    0.96366276  0.38344152]]
error: 
 [[ 0.79172504  0.52889492  0.56804456  0.92559664  0.07103606]
 [ 0.0871293   0.0202184   0.83261985  0.77815675  0.87001215]]
```

What am I missing here? I thought setting a seed allows for a deterministic behavior, but apparently this doesn't apply here! What is going on here?

Comment: Each created random number changes the internal state of the random number generator (otherwise it would return the same number again and again). You must reset it again (by setting seed) after the first array creation to get the same data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reseed the RNG every time.

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)
error = np.random.rand(2,5)
np.random.seed(0)
error2 = np.random.rand(2,5)
print('error: \n' ,error)
print('error2: \n' ,error2)
```

Otherwise you're just continuing the random sequence, not starting over.

Answer (score 1):

If a (pseudo) random number generator is (re)initialized with the same seed, it will produce the **same sequence of numbers**.

```
np.random.seed(0)
print (np.random.rand(),np.random.rand())
```

`0.5488135039273248 0.7151893663724195`

```
np.random.seed(0)
print (np.random.rand(),np.random.rand())
```

`0.5488135039273248 0.7151893663724195`

It will not be a (pseudo) random number generator if it generates the same random number every time for a seed. It will be some deterministic function `f(seed)`. When you seed it, the sequence of number are deterministic but the numbers them self are random.